# DataGridView custom cell should use normal ForeColor when selected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I made some custom `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` instances. In most of them I set custom `ForeColor` values and that works fine. But when the `SelectionMode` is `FullRowSelect` it overrides my `ForeColor` values for this cell.

I tried to set it in the Draw event when the cell is selcted but it does not work.

My cell is definde as follows.

```
public class CustomCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return base.GetFormattedValue(value, rowIndex, ref cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context);
        }

        if (value.ToString().Contains("test"))
        {
            cellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        return base.GetFormattedValue(value, rowIndex, ref cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context);
    }
}
```

I don't want to change the selection mode but I want to show this cell with its right `ForeColor` but the selection `BackColor`.

How could the solution to this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `Paint` method of cell and set `cellStyle.SelectionForeColor` to the same color of `ForeColor`:

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds,
    Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState,
    object value, object formattedValue,
    string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
    DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
    DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
{
    if (string.Format("{0}", formattedValue) == "something")
    {
        cellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        cellStyle.SelectionForeColor = cellStyle.ForeColor;
    }
    base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value,
        formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
}
```

**Note:** You can do the same using `CellFormatting` or `CellPainting` event of `DataGridView` without creating a custom cell.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I know that i can use the events. But I have a lot cells all over the program that should look the same way with some really special rules applied. So it was nicer to make custom cells for this.

Comment: You know the requirements better, I shared it just for your information or for future readers :)